# How to get decimal value in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

i am beginner in laravel i want to get 3 values after point  satrting from 0. e.g 0.001
there are two forms for one `number_format()` is working for 2nd its not working but i want to display in 2nd for. code of both forms is below.

working form.

```
  <div class="num">{{ number_format($total_deposit,3) }}</div>
```

not working form that is with data counters.

```
<div class="num" data-start="0" data-end="{{ number_format($total_deposit,3) }}" data-postfix="{{ $basic->symbol }}" data-duration="1500" data-delay="0">{{ number_format($total_deposit,3) }}</div>
```

Comment: Give an example of what not working means. 0.01? 0.0001?

Comment: Did you print/debug the value of $total_deposit?

Comment: @btl my deposit is in bitcoin that is 0.001 btc . but webpage is not showing 0.001. but if my deposit is in complete number e.g 1 and 100 then it shows

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display 3 zero's after the decimal you have to save that also in that type check your migration how you are saving the data

```
$table->decimal('total_deposit', 10, 3);
```

By using and saving from this approach your data will be save as per Zero you want after decimal here

10 = total numeric value you need before decimal in this case its Billion

3 = Total number of zero you want after decimal

next just display data without any php number format function you will get exact amount display.